# Application Design using XML

Tags: xml, jakarta-ee, architecture

I am developing an application which will basically interact with the MQ (hosted on client side). the data which is to displayed on the front end is comming from an very huge XML document (approx 0.5 MB of xml is being sent out by client MQ).

I tried converting the XSD into POJOS and tried using JAXB to store data in pojos, but some of the POJO files created are very huge (13 MB java file). Also,

what are the best suited approaches for such design? The underlying techstack is typical J2EE stack such as:

Java/J2ee
WAS 7.0
JQuery/CSS (Ajax is extensively used).
Servlets/Filters etc.

i am open for using any framework (Spring, Struts etc) provided it should decouple my Front end data and should help me in achiving a robust and maintenable design.

regards
Ashish

Answer (score 0):

Does your application need all the content in the xml or just parts of it?
If it is the latter, you could save the xml as a clob, design a more lightweight class that only maps the selected attributes/elements and go from there.
~ HTH